# Adding loss functions with different units together

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Given a model that has on two different outputs and uses different losses for those outputs and takes a mean of the losses for training:

- Categorical Cross Entropy for a classification output
- MSE for some regression output

How can I balance the training so it equally trains both outputs?

Initial losses recorded when started were:

- CCE = 0.6
- MSE = 5e-3

Ideal loss values are:

- CCE < 0.1
- MSE < 5e-7

If I let one loss reach my ideal range then increase the weights of the other one then the first loss might shift out of my ideal loss value range.

What's a good strategy to use with the weights to ensure both outputs are benefiting from the gradient descent equally?

```
model.compile(
...
            loss = {
                'classification' : classification_loss,
                'regression' : regression_loss,
            },
            loss_weights = {
                'classification' : 1,
                'regression' : 1,
            }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The weights can be dynamically adjusted during training with the help of a Keras callback:

```
class LossWeightsCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
       
        cce = logs.get('classification_loss') # Cross-entropy loss
        mse = logs.get('regression_loss') # Mean-square error loss
        epsilon = 1e-8
        # Compute the new weights
        ratio = cce / (mse + epsilon)  # adding epsilon to avoid division by zero
        self.model.loss_weights = {'classification': ratio / (1 + ratio), 'regression': 1 / (1 + ratio)}
```

Then, pass this callback when fitting your model:

```
model.fit(..., callbacks=[LossWeightsCallback()])
```

N.B. The callback parameter, logs, is supplied by Keras to custom callbacks overriding on_batch_end().